# how to update Boolean type column - Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I have a boolean column in my database for image thumbnail. One selected row will be thumbnail (and will have a value `1`) and other rows will be `0`. How do i update the selected row value into `1` and others `0`.[image]

when i run this update function, it will update the row every time against the ID (off course).

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $id = (int) $id;

    $image = HotelGallery::where('id', $id)
                            ->update(['is_thumbnail' => '1']);

    return response()->json(['success' => 'Done']);
}
```

[image]

ID `2` and `3` have value `1`, how do i update this **is_thumbnail** row against the **ID** which is `3`, will be `1` and others **is_thumbnail** rows should be `0` in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you want in a hotel_id have only is_thumbnail=1:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $id = (int) $id;

    $hotelGallery = HotelGallery::where('id', $id)
                            ->pluck('hotel_id')->toArray();
    $hotel_id = array_get($hotelGallery, '0', 0);
    // Set is_thumbnail = 0 for all image of hotel_id
    HotelGallery::where('hotel_id', $hotel_id)
                        ->update(['is_thumbnail' => 0]);

    $image = HotelGallery::where('id', $id)->update(['is_thumbnail' => 1]);

    return response()->json(['success' => 'Done']);
}
```

Comment: Yes exactly, each hotel will have one `is_thumbnail = 1`, that's mean i will have to run 2 queries, first for update all rows of `is_thumbnail=0` against `hotel_id`, and second query will update `is_thumbnail=1` against `image_id` which is `$id`.

Comment: Yes, you should run two query. If you have request hotel_id better.

Answer (score 0):

```
//To Update row two as shown in above image 
query="UPDATE $data_base_name.$data_base_table SET `is_thumbnail`=0 WHERE `id`=2";
result=mysqli_query($conn,(query));

//To Update row two as shown in above image (being more specific)
query="UPDATE $data_base_name.$data_base_table SET `is_thumbnail`=false WHERE `id`=2";
result=mysqli_query($conn,(query));
```

The above code will change row two `is_thumbail` to 0 for value as 1 change 'false'or'0' in the above code to '1' or 'true'.

```
//Update to improved question (updating all rows)
query="
UPDATE $data_base_name.$data_base_table SET `is_thumbnail`=true WHERE `id`=2;
UPDATE $data_base_name.$data_base_table SET `is_thumbnail`=false WHERE `id`!=2;";
result=mysqli_multi_query($conn,(query));
while (mysqli_next_result($conn)){;}//this is to free result set for multi query
```

The above query will set row two to 'true' or '1' and every other row to 'false' or '0'.

If your new to php please read about SQL injections!!! see also https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

```
//Update to improved question (eloquent format)
Table::where('id', '=',2 )->update(['is_thumbnail' => 'true']);  
Table::where('id', '!=',2 )->update(['is_thumbnail' => 'false']);
```

This not the best way to do it in laravel but this should work for now.

Comment: okay, when i update the row 2 `is_thumbnail` to `1` other rows `1,3,4` should be `0` as well.

Comment: i edited the answer to show the code you asked try that.

Comment: i got you, is there any way to implement this multi query into laravel eloquent models?

Comment: yes have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries

Comment: i have read this before, but i'm still not able to update records with multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi queries in [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

PDO example :

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'root', '');

// works regardless of statements emulation
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 0);


$thumbnail_id = 2;

$sql = 'UPDATE tab SET tab.is_thumbnail = false;' . "\n" .
       'UPDATE tab SET tab.is_thumbnail = true WHERE tab.id = ?';
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$thumbnail_id]);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to run this query into **Laravel eloquent** update models?

Answer (score 0):

Best Laravel way is to integrate this function in model:

```
class HotelGallery extends Model
{
  protected static function boot ()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::saving(function($model) {
            if($model->attributes['is_thumbnail'] == 1)
            {
                (new self)->where('hotel_id', $model->attributes['hotel_id'])->where('id', '<>', $model->attributes['id'] ?? 0)->update(['is_thumbnail' => 0]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```